# Как вызвать каллбэк из класса?

Tags: c#, классы

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Есть необходимость установить каллбэк в класс. Как это делается на шарпе? В инетах ни чего не могу найти (скорее всего по неправильным словам ищу).

Извиняюсь, если в шарпе данная технология называется не так.

Суть:

Нужно сделать, чтобы класс при определенном событии "дернул" за указанную функцию, причем класс является закрытым, и ссылку на эту функцию нужно передавать в качестве аргумента метода этого класса.

Пример:

Как передать ссылку на функцию(метод) классу я уже разобрался:

```
private Func<Delegate> _onDisconnect;

public ConnectionManager SetDisconnectionCallback(Func<Delegate> f) {
    _onDisconnect = f;
    return GetInstance;
}
```

А вот, собственно, сам вопрос: как теперь за эту функцию дернуть?

Спасибо!

Comment: Оказалось, что я даже метод неправильно объявил.

Как мне нужно:

public void SomeMethod(){
ConnectionManager.GetInstance().SetDisconnectionCallback( OnDisconnect() ).Connect();
}

public void OnDisconnect(){
 // Some code
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ConnectionManager SetDisconnectionCallback(Func<Delegate> f) {
    _onDisconnect = f;
    return GetInstance;
}

private void InvokeMyCallback()
{
    if (_onDisconnect != null)
        _onDisconnect();
}
```

В идеале, наверное, лучше событие сделать, чем просто Delegate хранить...

```
class MyClass
{
    public event EventHandler Disconnect;

    protected virtual void OnDisconnect(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Disconnect;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
        OnDisconnect(EventArgs.Empty);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Оказалось, что я даже метод неправильно объявил.

Как мне нужно:

public void SomeMethod(){
ConnectionManager.GetInstance().SetDisconnectionCallback( OnDisconnect() ).Connect();
}

public void OnDisconnect(){
 // Some code
}

Comment: А каким образом сделать событие? Можно пример? Буду премного благодарен!

Comment: Func<T> - универсальный делегат с возвращаемым типом T.

Action - универсальный делегат с возвращаемым типом void.

Аналогично существует N универсальных делегатов с параметрами Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult>, например и Action<T1, T2, T3>, например.

Comment: если OnDisconnect() ничего не должен возвращать, то хватит и Action.

Comment: Возвращать ни чего не должен, слушатель сам должен прочитать нужные поля класса. 

Сейчас пробую сделать так:

`    public event Action OnDisconnection;

    public virtual void OnOnDisconnection() {
        Action handler = OnDisconnection;
        if (handler != null)
            handler();
    }
`

Из слушателя назначать:

`                ConnectionManager cm = ConnectionManager.GetInstance;
                cm.OnDisconnection = OnConnectionDisconnect();
                cm.SendToServer(new PckInit(4935, 0, 999, 9762));`

Разумеется, не работает - нельзя так назначать. А как можно?

Comment: Как на это событие слушателя-то подписать? (Прошу прощения за глупые вопросы, годы дельфи и джавы не прошли даром, шарп не могу понять ещё толком).

UPD: Сообразил:

`                ConnectionManager cm = ConnectionManager.GetInstance;
                cm.OnDisconnection += new EventHandler(this.OnConnectionDisconnect);
                cm.SendToServer(new PckInit(4935, 0, 999, 9762));`

А как передать именно делегата из слушателя?